# How can I make cloud firestore more secure without authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an application that pulls data from cloud firestore. this app does not receive user login but firestore sent me an email saying it is not secure. [mail of firestore security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vBmx.png)
There seems to be a security problem in authentication, but I don't want user login.
Here are my current "Cloud firestore Rules" settings:
`

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}`
```

How can I make this more secure?
Can I limit the number of reads as another solution?

Comment: Instead of using a wilcard `/{document=**}` you can assign the rule only to intended collections making it a bit more secure. `/collectionName/${docid'}`

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will also help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're allowing not authenticated users to read your whole database. Another one is your authenticated users can create in your database what ever they want.
You need to restrict more access to your database. Someone will make his own database out of your database. He can create a document in a collection you expect should exist. This document will have nested collection with his database and everyone can read it. The best part is, if you have thousands of documents in your collection, you won't find that one document with nested collection easy.

To prevent that, restrict access to the whole database:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false; 
    }
    match /articles/{articleID} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}`
```